# Display file URL on file upload

Tags: php, html, file

I used the tutorial from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. The code works fine, although I have a question: Is there a way to make the page display the file's URL after the  upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the move_uploaded_file function did it's functionality, you may concat the base url with target dir and file name!

for example:

```
echo "www.example.com/".$target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

or simply use:

```
echo "www.example.com/".$target_file;
```

Comment: It works well. Is there a way to make it include the `%20` in the spaces in the filename? If not, that's okay too.

Comment: You may use urlencode() function

Comment: You can accept the answerer if it helped you @CMFdev without adding additional hostage requirements via comments. In the meantime I'll +1